# Constructor undefined

Tags: java

I have a problem with my code, in that it keeps saying that the constructor is undefined. I already read somewhere that I need to declare the constructor with no arguments. I just don't know how to do that.

If someone could help, I am new at java and programming. My code is below:

```
import java.util.*;//import library



class Input
{

    public Input (int size,int startV,int endingV)
      {

         //declarations of variables
        double difference;
        double[] array= new double[size];

        array[0]=startV;

     //calculating the difference to add on each number in the array
     difference=(endingV-startV)/size;

    for (int counter=1;counter<size;counter++) //for loop to fill the array
              {
        array[counter]=array[counter-1] + difference;           
          }


      }

    public Input enter(int size,int startV,int endingV)
      {

        //declarations of variables
        double difference;
        double[] array= new double[size];

        array[0]=startV;

             //calculating the difference to add on each number in the array
        difference=(endingV-startV)/size; 

            for (int counter=1;counter<size;counter++) //for loop to fill the array
        {
            array[counter]=array[counter-1] + difference;           
        }

            return this;
    }
}

class Show
{
    public Show (int size,double[] array)
    {

        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) //for loop to print the array
            System.out.println("This is the array " + i+ ": " + array[i]);

    }

    public Show print(int size,double[] array)
    {

        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) //for loop to print the array
        System.out.println("This is the array " + i+ ": " + array[i]);

        return this;
    }
}

public class Assignment2 
{

    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
        //declaring variables
        int startV,endingV;
        int size=0;



        System.out.print("Give the size of the array:");//Print message on screen
        size = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();//asking for the size of array

            double[] array= new double[size]; //creation of array

    System.out.print("Give the starting value of the array:");
    startV = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();//asking for the starting value of array

    System.out.print("Give the ending value of the array:");
    endingV = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();//asking for the last value of array

    //calling the functions from the other classes 

        Input enter= new Input(size,startV,endingV);
        Show print= new Show(size,array);

    }



}
```

Comment: Error is here 
  Method enter= new Method(size,startV,endingV);
  Method1 print= new Method1(size,array);

Comment: Do not use `double Difference` -- keep variable and method names camelCase and use PascalCase for class names. For example, `double difference`. (Notice how StackOverflow changes the colour of "Difference" to blue? That's because, by convention, in Java, words that begin with an uppercase are considered classes.) Also, avoid using the word `Method` as the name of a class -- it is very confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You're close:

You have a method:

```
public Method enter(int size,int startV,int endingV) {
```

to make it a constructor it's signature must be

```
public Method (int size,int startV,int endingV) {
```

and you then have to delete the `return this;` statement.

Remember, constructors don't have a return type and their name is identical to the name of the class. With this information, you'll also be able to fix the `Method1` constructor.

---

Also, please respect the Java naming conventions and have variables start with a lower-case letter to improve the readability of your code.

Comment: Ok i fixed that one but now i have a new error. My array returns 0 values. Before i put everything in classes I had them in functions and the program was printing correct values.Now i get:
Give the size of the array:10
Give the starting value of the array:10
Give the ending value of the array:210
This is the array 0: 0.0
This is the array 1: 0.0
This is the array 2: 0.0
This is the array 3: 0.0
This is the array 4: 0.0
This is the array 5: 0.0
This is the array 6: 0.0
This is the array 7: 0.0
This is the array 8: 0.0
This is the array 9: 0.0

Comment: @AntreasSolou: Glad to help. That exceeds the scope of the question you posted. If you can't figure out why it's happening (with a debugger) feel free to post a new question :)

Comment: @AntreasSolou: You should try to debug before posting here. Your following question was about 8 minutes after my comment here. That doesn't show that you first tried to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a

```
public Method(size,startV,endingV)
```

not

```
public Method enter = (size, startV, endingV)
```

The first is a constructor the second is a method

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor must have the same name than your class and has no return type. So for your class `Method`, your constructor will simply be :

```
public Method(int size, int startV, int endingV)
{
    // code...
}
```

Please also note that constructors exist to initialize your instances of objects, if you want to create a method that does a specific calcul, then yes, you'll have to do :

```
public int enter(int size, int startV, int endingV)
{
     int result = 0;
     // code to calculate, for example result = size + startV + endingV ...
     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For class Method

the default constructor will be

```
public Method(){}
```

For class Method1

the default constructor will be

```
public Method1(){}
```

in your classes there are no constructors as the

constructor name must be will the same as class name.

```
enter(int size,int startV,int endingV)
```

and

```
print(int size,double[] array)
```

can be two methods in your classes.

also your two constructor can be -

```
public Method(int size,int startV,int endingV){ /..../}
```

and

```
public Method1(int size,double[] array){ /..../}
```